# Add custom view in xib file

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xib

So I have a custom view created(with a xib file) and I'm trying to use it in another xib file...but it's not showing. In that xib file I have a view and I've set the custom class field to my custom view's name.

However, this view is not showing.

I don't want to draw this view programmatically, I want to use a xib file - how do I do this?

I'm not sure what code I can post up - just tell me in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a method to directly drawing a custom view with a xib to another xib, but a thing you can do is:

- assing the file owner to the view controller of the xib you want to put the custom one in.
- assign the view as an IBOutlet of that controller.
- when you need the outlet simply call: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"your_custom_view_xib_name" owner:self options:nil];`, at this point the outlet previously created will be set.
- set the outlet as subview of the view